3/2 Sobolev Norm on the boundary of a bounded open subset of $\Bbb R^n$
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a open bounded set and $\partial\Omega$ be the boundary of $\Omega$.
Following the reference text by Alois Kufner, Oldřich John and Svatopluk Fučík, Function spaces,
(Monographs and Textbooks on Mechanics of Solids and Fluids. Mechanics: Analysis 3. Leyden: Noordhoff International Publishing.  XV, 454 p. (1977), MR482102, Zbl 0364.46022), I know that for $0<s<1$
$$\|u\|_{s,\partial\Omega}^{2}=\int_{\partial\Omega}|u(y)|^{2}dS+\int_{\partial\Omega}\int_{\partial\Omega}\dfrac{|u(x)-u(y)|^{2}}{|x-y|^{n-1+2s}}dS_{x}dS_{y},$$
and also for $s>1$, I know
$$\|u\|^{2}_{s,\Omega}=\|u\|^{2}_{[s],\Omega}+\sum_{|\alpha|=[s]}\|D^{\alpha}u\|^{2}_{\{s\},\Omega}$$
My question is that: for $s>1$ does this equality holds
$$\|u\|^{2}_{s,\partial\Omega}=\|u\|^{2}_{[s],\partial\Omega}+\sum_{|\alpha|=[s]}\|D^{\alpha}u\|^{2}_{\{s\},\partial\Omega}\;?$$
If so can you please suggest some reference where this is stated?
Thanks

Welcome to MO. Without further information, your question is a bit nonsensical and essentially becomes a chicken-and-egg question. Whether the stated identity is true or not depends on the way the function space $H^s(\partial \Omega)$ (or however it is called in your reference) is defined in the first place. Of course you could define it exactly via the norm expression that you state---it is certainly, in a sense, a natural one---, but then you would have to reconcile that with a possibly different definition in your reference.

Also note that $\partial\Omega$ needs sufficient regularity for the expression to make sense. On irregular domains, usually different definitions can lead to different spaces. What is your assumption on $\partial\Omega$ and how it is connected to the value of $s$? For $1<s<2$, for example, a $C^{1,1}$ boundary is an adequate assumption.
